# What kind of hardware information is accessible for computers on a network?

Tags: networking, cpu, mac-address, serial-number

If a computer is connected to say, your job's network what kind of hardware information can be retrieved. More specifically can an administrator get a list of all the CPU's and there serial numbers/identification numbers by a computer just being connected to the network?

Is there any possible way to gather this information without running something like CPUID locally?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how it's "connected" to the network.

If you just bring your home laptop in and plug it into the network the best they'll probably learn is the MAC address of your computer, from which they may be able to discern the manufacturer of that NIC.

This is assuming you've secured the laptop with a firewall and have things like open (file) shares (etc.) turned off.

If you've left remote management services, remote file services, etc. enabled with no firewall or specific security enabled, or if you've joined their domain, then they can see (basically) whatever they want by using things such as [WMI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Management_Instrumentation), [SNMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snmp), etc.

Comment: alright, and in my specific case its a stock install of windows 7 connected to my job's wired network. So would that allow them to view such information?

Comment: You should only be able to get the (purported) manufacturer of the Network Card - which often reflects the device maker from the MAC address.  If you can get anything more [in the general case], you have a security problem on your hands.

Comment: Again how is it "connected"?  Just plugged in?  What edition of Windows 7? Is the firewall enabled?  Perhaps, if your worried about it, just don't use your computer on _their_ network. :)

Answer (score 0):

Its not practical to get information like number of CPU's etc remotely.

There are a few theoretical things which might help you make a slightly better then random guess, but thats about it.  (For example stress testing the system and seeing how it performs, fingerprinting the OS and coming to conclusions, watching the traffic  [ for example HTTP headers ] and making inferences.   (And looking at MAC addresses as posited above)

At the end of the day, a network is really a connection between devices using a defined protocol.  There is no need to know more then how to route packets for a network to work, so building in additional functionality is a waste of resources (and arguably a bad idea for a whole lot of other reasons, eg privacy, security)